# How To run Animation and an Action of same sprite simultaneously in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have an Animation which is present in forever loop
and i want to run an action with it. want to run
both animation and action at same time.

For Example : Changing Ball Color (Animation) and Buncing it (Action) .

Comment: I dunno `-x-` but in objc there is a CCActionSpawn.  A quick look around shows that [this](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/cplusplus/v3x/dc/df1/classcocos2d_1_1_spawn.html) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to do it

1) you can use Spawn action

```
auto spawnAnimationAction = Spawn::create(colorAnimation, bounceAction, NULL);
ball->runAction(spawnAnimationAction);
```

2) you can create a ball Node and add ball sprite as a child to ball node.
apply animation on ball sprite and bounce action on ball node.

```
auto ballNode = Node::create();
auto ballSprite = Sprite::create("filename.png" );
ballSprite->runAction(colorAnimation);
ballNode->addChild(ballSprite);
ballNode->runAction(bounceAction);
```

3)You can create your own custom Action class which will handle both color animation and bounce action

Answer (score 1):

You can also call `runAction()` once for each action.

```
node->runAction(animationAction);
node->runAction(bounceAction);
```